# Qt Android Deployment Error: Cannot find the androiddeploy Json file

Tags: android, qt, sdk, android-ndk

I am having issues on deploying my android application to my phone. This error will pop up whenever i try to release my application (Error: Cannot find the androiddeploy Json file.). And i have checked my all my development kits and it seem that Qt had approved its settings. Thanks.

Cannot find the androiddeploy Json file.
Error while building/deploying project swipe (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (Clang Qt 5.9.8 for Android ARMv7))
When executing step "Deploy to Android device"

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it helps, but I faced the exact same problem and I solved it by just unchecking the "Shadow build" checkbox under "Build settings" (ctrl+5). After that, everything worked.

- Target device: Lenovo tabM10 FHD plus
- Qt version: 5.15.2
- Qt Creator version: 4.14.2